# How can I change data type from object to string in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, string

Below shows my data type:

```
CREATE_TIME        object
```

I want to change the 'CREATE_TIME' from object to string, and I had tried the below code '.astype()' but not works.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date, timedelta
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\xxx\yyy.csv', index_col=0)
df['CREATE_TIME'] = df['CREATE_TIME'].astype('str')
```

Can you guys please help me?
Thanks.

Comment: What exactly happened when you tried the code?

Comment: what do you mean by not works you have to provide more details edit your question and add the details what is not working what you are expecting

Comment: There is no string data type in pandas ... yet. For now, it is `object`. There is an experimental `StringDtype` but usually people just use `object`. Although `StringDtype` is probably the future. Read the following: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/text.html

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Because I want to strftime my code but the error told me that the 'create_time' is not string type, so I want to convert it to string before strftime the data.

Comment: start_date = date(2020,4,1)
end_date   = date(2020,4,30)
delta      = timedelta(days=1)

while start_date <= end_date:
    logs=df[df['CREATE_TIME'].str.contains(start_date.strftime("%Y/%-m/%-d"))]
    logs.to_csv(r'C:\xxx\chatlog-'+start_date.strftime("%Y%m%d")+'.csv')
    print(start_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
    start_date = start_date + delta

I want to use the code above to extract data from specific column in csv and export it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not convert it using apply() and str():

```
df['CREATE_TIME'] = df.apply(lambda row: str(row['CREATE_TIME']), axis=1)
```

Comment: it doesn't work. :(

Comment: well it worked for me on a bunch of random objects and converted they return on a __repr__ call! I have no idea what data you are operating on. And are you saying this specific line doesn't work or the rest of your program fails later when converting to dates? You didn't say anything about dates in your original question. I suggest if you want to parse some dates, do an apply with a function that does a try..except to handle errors and if there's errors in the data, then it'll tell you what they are